# File Download using Javascript / Angularjs, whose content is retrieved in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, binary

I have downloaded the file from a REST api, but its content is displayed in this format.
I wish to download it instantaneously in the browser whenever it is called.

{"0":"�","1":"�","2":"�","3":"�","4":"\u0000","5":"\u0010","6":"J","7":"F","8":"I","9":"F","10":"\u0000","11":"\u0001","12":"\u0001","13":"\u0000","14":"\u0000","15":"\u0001","16":"\u0000","17":"\u0001","18":"\u0000","19":"\u0000","20":"�","21":"�","22":"\u0000","23":"C","24":"\u0000","25":"\b","26":"\u0006","27":"\u0006","28":"\u0007","29":"\u0006","30":"\u0005","31":"\b","32":"\u0007","33":"\u0007","34":"\u0007","35":"\t","36":"\t","37":"\b","38":"\n","39":"\f","40":"\u0014","41":"\r","42":"\f","43":"\u000b","44":"\u000b","45":"\f","46":"\u0019","47":"\u0012","48":"\u0013","49":"\u000f","50":"\u0014","51":"\u001d","52":"\u001a","53":"\u001f"}

Answer (score 0):

Use the browser's webdeveloper tools (F12 in Chrome, firebug in firefox, F12 or F10 in IE) and check the request you're making for the file. Check the content type and the format of the response. From what I'm seing, I think the "file" is recognized on the client side as a JavaScript array.

Also consider setting the encoding from server-side.

Comment: The response content type is
Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8

How to change the content type

I tried adding headers in $resource but it is not working.

var resource= $resource('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/:one/:two', {}, {
  getfile:{method:'GET',params:{one:'files',two:'auto/@path'},headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}}}....

Comment: if you want to set headers, you also have to put a data field (even if it's empty and you're doing a GET; don't ask me why). Try: var resource= $resource('api-content.dropbox.com/1/:one/:two';, {}, { getfile:{method:'GET',params:{one:'files',two:'auto/@path'},headers:{'Content-‌​Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}, data: ''}}